# Word 2010 VSTO Spacing Font Property - is it available in API?

Tags: vsto

Is it possible to access this option in VSTO:

```
Right click on paragraph -> Font -> Advanced Tab -> Spacing Option
```

and change it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. These are the different parameters with which you can interact.

```
Sub Sample()
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "+Body"
        .Size = 11
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = 0 ' wdUnderlineNone
        .UnderlineColor = -16777216  'wdColorAutomatic
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .Emboss = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Hidden = False
        .SmallCaps = False
        .AllCaps = False
        .Color = -16777216
        .Engrave = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Spacing = -1.1
        .Scaling = 150
        .Position = 4
        .Kerning = 0
        .Animation = 0 'wdAnimationNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @dragonfly: Feel free to close this question if your query is solved :)